# Cannot find Azure Service Principal that I created

Tags: azure, azure-service-principal

I suspect that I'm looking at something the wrong way, completely.

I've created a Service Connection in Azure DevOps that allows access to an Azure Machine Learning workspace. And this works fine too.

When the DevOps pipeline agent issues an `az account show`, (part of) the output is like this:

```
    "tenantId": "b8c ... 5ba",
    "user": {
      "name": "***",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
```

So a Service Principal is present. But I can't find it in Entra ID.

Thanks to [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31299/josh) I now know that a Service Principal apparently is synonymous with Enterprise Application.

Indeed, in the Enterprise Application list (under Entra ID) I find a likely candidate for my Service Principal (by creation date).

However, I have a hard time verifying exactly that it is actually the precise one being used.

The attributes shown of the Enterprise Application are:

```
Name
Application ID
Object ID
```

but in the service connection details I only have:

```
Subscription
Resource Group
Service Connection name
```

and in the output above (from the pipeline agent), I only have a tenant ID and the user name is three asterixes: *** (which I also find fishy).

The Service Connection name was created by me and is not the same as the Enterprise Application name, so I can't use that.

So ... **how to verify exactly that my candidate is indeed that particular service principal** ... ? I would need to know for sure because I want to extend the Service Principal with a particular role ...

PS. Some pointers to (accessible) reading material to get a good grasp on this are welcome, I probably miss reasoning power due to lacking knowledge.

Comment: Did you ensure to filter for this? Under Enterprise applications -> Under Application Type, choose All Applications and then select Apply. Sometimes the filter is only for a limited subset

Comment: Hi, yes, I removed all filters. Are you suggesting the Application should show up in the list under the name I gave to the service connection?

Comment: When you go to your Project Settings in Azure DevOps and Service Connections, which `Service connection type` did you create? Azure Resource Manager using SPN auth? If you click "Manage Service Principal" it should take you to it in Azure. My name for it is "DevOpsOrg-DevOpsProject-SubId". This I can also find in Enterprise Applications.

Comment: Hi, if I click "Manage Service Principal" I indeed get to the the app with the exact name that you say! However, then I click on "App roles" and I see "No app roles have been added" (I would expect "Contributor" since it manipulates the ML Workspace). Also, when I click on "Manage Service Connection Roles" (from the service connection details), then I get to the expected ML workspace details. When I do "check access" (in IAM) and then check "User, group or service principal", then nothing shows up ... do you know why that is? Probably not a bug, but I find it disturbing :|

Comment: Take the object id or the name and look it up in enterprise applications and see if it has any roles assigned there?

Comment: Did this solve your question? If so, I’ll create an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do. I hesitate to accept that the situation is like so: 1) I cannot get a list of Service Principals and 2) From the detail view of the Enterprise Application, it is not possible to disclose that it has a Contributor role in some ML resource group. How would an Azure administrator then know this important fact if only given the Enterprise Application name or ID? I'm not ready to believe this. So, no, deeply sorry, but my question is not solved and I am not ready to believe that is is just as it seems now. Can't be like that, can it?

Answer (score 1):

It’ll be in the Entra (formerly AAD) area under enterprise applications. Be sure to clear the filters before searching by name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did get me a bit further, but not there yet. I expanded my question, which still stands unfortunately. +1 For answering, though.